# deploying to google app engine flexible env

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-flexible

i am following 
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-app-engine

but when i run 
gcloud service-management deploy openapi.yaml

i am hitting:
ERROR: (gcloud.service-management.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Not allowed to get project settings for project instasmarttagger-162719

i am not sure what i have to do to resolve it.

the openapi.yml looks like

```
VSKUMAR-mac:appengine vskumar$ vi openapi.yaml 

      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Authenication info."
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/authInfoResponse"
      x-security:
      - google_id_token:
          audiences:
          # Your OAuth2 client's Client ID must be added here. You can add
          # multiple client IDs to accept tokens from multiple clients.
          - "YOUR-CLIENT-ID"
definitions:
  echoMessage:
    properties:
      message:
        type: "string"
  authInfoResponse:
    properties:
      id:
        type: "string"
      email:
        type: "string"
# This section requires all requests to any path to require an API key.
security:
- api_key: []
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
  # This section configures authentication using Google API Service Accounts
  # to sign a json web token. This is mostly used for server-to-server
  # communication.
  google_jwt:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    # This must match the 'iss' field in the JWT.
    x-google-issuer: "jwt-client.endpoints.sample.google.com"
    # Update this with your service account's email address.
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL"
  # This section configures authentication using Google OAuth2 ID Tokens.
  # ID Tokens can be obtained using OAuth2 clients, and can be used to access
  # your API on behalf of a particular user.
  google_id_token:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "accounts.google.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
```

Comment: maybe start here: https://cloud.google.com/service-management/troubleshooting#how_do_i_fix_permission_denied_errors

Answer (score 3):

Looks like i was signed into a different account and was trying to deploy to the app hosted on another account.  doing a gcloud list projects helped me identify it